# How Do I Display the X amount of days since January 1, 1970 in Java

Tags: java

I was wondering what is the best way to solve this problem on java ranch.

http://www.javaranch.com/geekWatch.jsp

Thanks

Comment: Use JodaTime or Java 8's Time API

Comment: @Dan Please copy or restate the pertinent parts of your sourced document. StackOverflow is intended to be an authoritative source, so mere links are frowned upon because of link-rot and other issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general idea can be

1. Get the number of seconds(For this understand the Date API in java.) since Jan 1, 1970.
2. Get the value of seconds in a day 24hrs*60min*60secs.

Now divide the value obtained in 1. by that of 2.
This will give you the number of days.

Comment: There isn't always 24 hours in a day or 60 seconds in a minute ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use either JodaTime or Java 8's Time API (or some other dedicated library)

```
LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC);
LocalDateTime then = LocalDateTime.of(1970, Month.JANUARY, 1, 0, 0);

Duration duration = Duration.between(then, now);
System.out.println(duration.toDays());
```

Which outputs

```
16748
```

Comment: This code could be off by a day because of ignoring time zone. The count-from-epoch presumes UTC. By getting "now" as a "Local" without specifying a time zone of UTC means the answer is off by the amount of hours in the current default time zone. I suggest using `ZonedDateTime` or passing `ZoneOffset.UTC` to the `now` method.